# How can I have a dynamic picklist that gets updated when the new value is absent?

Tags: picklist

I need to create a picklist field, that will have an option to add values that are NOT in the original list. The values are coming from a SF form.

1. If you add the new data today, it is inserted, and shown in reports - but it can NOT be selected in filters and/or bucket values.
2. This option should also be available from the SF interface

I thought of having a text field, that if there is data there, it should be added to the picklist values, but I am not sure that it's the way.

For example:
I have a picklist with name list: John, Jane, Jo

Someone needs to enter a new value: Boby

Boby will NOT be visible, even if I would like to change Boby to something else in the picklist field edit page, I will not see it.

I will need Boby to be added as a valid value.

Comment: Be aware that there is a maximum limit of 15000 characters / 1000 entries on a picklist, so if you build a mechanism which allows users to add them you may need to consider housekeeping the data somehow too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add additional values to a picklist, you need to use the Metadata API. Take a look at this [GitHub project](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) to see how it is possible to access the Metadata API from within Apex. I think you should be able to do an update of the picklist field with new values. Take a look at the documentation on the [picklist component](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_picklist.htm#kanchor122)